# this.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. I want to write a javascript code that when I click a button, the alert window pops up and writes data-message attribute. Here is my code:

```
<button type="button" data-message="a1" onclick="pop()">click</button>

<script>
  function pop() {
    alert(this.getAttribute("data-message"));
  }
</script>
```

but I get the error

```
TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function
alert(this.getAttribute("data-message"));
```

I have two questions:

1. What is wrong?
2. How can I debug this? How can I find out what `this` refers to? I am using firebug.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need send `this` on the button like

```
<button type="button" data-message="a1" onclick="pop(this)">click</button>
```

and the Js, capture who is calling it.

```
function pop(e) {
    alert(e.getAttribute("data-message"));
  }
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qGMU2/)

Comment: @user2725109 Don't worry :)

Answer (score 6):

In your function, `this` is the `window` object, and it has no `getAttribute` method. You need to pass `this` as an argument from the `onclick` attribute:

```
<button type="button" data-message="a1" onclick="pop(this)">click</button>

<script>
  function pop(button) {
    alert(button.getAttribute("data-message"));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, you need to pass `this` in your onclick function.

```
<button type="button" data-message="a1" onclick="pop(this)">click</button>

function pop(element) {
  alert(element.getAttribute("data-message"));
}
```

For a better understanding of why this is the case, [this is a good read](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html). That page describes, in great detail, your *exact* scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Or jquery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".message").on("click", function()
    {
        console.log($('.message').data('message'));
    });
});
</script>

<button type="button" class="message" data-message="a1">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also inline

`<button type="button" data-message="a1" onclick="function pop(this); pop(button);pop(alert(button.getAttribute("data-message"));)">click</button>`

Answer (score 0):

***DOM*** actually provides a set of ***API*** to access HTML elements, and *this* pointer points to the scope of the object, which can only access the attributes ***class, ID, style***, etc.

In the scope of the object, that is, you can access through the object attributes (***this.data-message***). However, there is no ***getAttribute()*** method in the scope of the object, so you cannot use ***this.getAttribute()**.*